# Converting multiple visio file to pdf through Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, macros, visio

I am facing problem with this code.
Objective of this code is to convert all the visio file kept in folder to pdf from EXCEL VBA macro...

With this code I am able to open visio file but not able convert to pdf file....it showing "Object Required " error....

```
FName = myPath & myFile
    Dim objDoc: Set objeDoc = VisioApp.documents.Open(FName)
objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat VisFixedFormatTypes = 1, FName, VisDocExIntent = 1, VisPrintOutRange = 0
```

I am facing problem with above lines

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim FName As String

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings
'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.vsd"
'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
'Loop through each Excel file in folder

  Do While myFile <> ""


    Set VisioApp = CreateObject("Visio.Application")
    FName = myPath & myFile
    Dim objDoc: Set objeDoc = VisioApp.documents.Open(FName)

   'Application.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat visFixedFormatPDF, "C:\Users\20098323\Desktop\BHAVIK\VAC-30001.pdf", visDocExIntentPrint, visPrintAll, 1, 53, False, True, True, True, False
objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat VisFixedFormatTypes = 1, FName, VisDocExIntent = 1, VisPrintOutRange = 0
      myFile = Dir
  Loop
'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"
ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Unless you've added a reference to the Visio object library then VBA doesn't recognize those visXxxxxx constants.   If you used Option Explicit that would alert you to the problem.

Comment: But what kind of change I should do in this code?

Comment: Add Option Explicit at the top of your code module.  That will point out to you that you've misspelled your variable as `objeDoc`. Also I'm not sure what you're doing with those parameters but that's not along the lines of any of my suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set VisioApp = CreateObject("Visio.Application")
FName = myPath & myFile
VisioApp.documents.Open FName
Application.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat visFixedFormatPDF, _
             FName, visDocExIntentPrint, visPrintAll, _
             1, 53, False, True, True, True, False
```

Here you create an instance of Visio `VisioApp`, but in the last line you use `Application` - this will by default refer to Excel where your code is running, not to Visio.  You need to replace that with `VisioApp`.

Also, you are using certain constants defined by the Visio object libary (`visFixedformatPDF`, etc).  Excel VBA doesn't know the values of these constants, so you can do one of:

1. Add a reference in your Excel VBProject to the Visio Object Library
2. Replace the constants with their numeric values (which you can look up in the Visio VBE Object Browser)
3. Define the constants and thier values at the top of your Excel VBA code.  Eg:

   Const visFixedFormatPDF = 1

Comment: I 

I Have changed my code as below...Nw it showing "object required " error...

FName = myPath & myFile
    Dim objDoc: Set objeDoc = VisioApp.documents.Open(FName)
    
   'Application.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat visFixedFormatPDF, "C:\Users\20098323\Desktop\BHAVIK\VAC-30001.pdf", visDocExIntentPrint, visPrintAll, 1, 53, False, True, True, True, False
objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat VisFixedFormatTypes = 1, FName, VisDocExIntent = 1, VisPrintOutRange = 0

Comment: Update your question to add your modified code, and indicate exactly which line has the error.